# Sublime will not run my code in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, sublimetext2

When I try to run my html on chrome using sublime 2 I get this alert: Error trying to parse build system: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing bracket in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Chrome.sublime-build:2:17. What does this mean?

Comment: Your `Chrome.sublime-build` file is not valid JSON and the problem is on or around line 2, column 17. Check there for things like missing commas, double quotes, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Write your HTML code in Sublime, save as .html file and then right click said file and select "Open With" then select chrome.